# Strimzi KafkaConnector not reading database credentials from secrets

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, strimzi

I'm practicing running Debezium following the [Official Documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/kubernetes.html) using Docker Desktop.

The commands are pretty much just copy and paste from the page except that the output registry and plugin URL for custom Kafka Connect image is replaced.

After the step creating a KafkaConnector, I didn't find the connector running at all.

I tried checking with commands below:

```
kubectl describe kafkaconnector debezium-connector-mysql -n debezium-example
kubectl describe kafkaconnect debezium-connect-cluster -n debezium-example
```

Outputs are shown as follows:
Kafka Connector:

```
Name:         debezium-connector-mysql
Namespace:    debezium-example
Labels:       strimzi.io/cluster=debezium-connect-cluster
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
Kind:         KafkaConnector
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-03-24T07:46:09Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:strimzi.io/cluster:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:class:
        f:config:
          .:
          f:database.hostname:
          f:database.include.list:
          f:database.password:
          f:database.port:
          f:database.server.id:
          f:database.user:
          f:schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers:
          f:schema.history.internal.kafka.topic:
          f:tasks.max:
          f:topic.prefix:
        f:tasksMax:
    Manager:         kubectl-create
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2023-03-24T07:46:09Z
  Resource Version:  206115
  UID:               2aef7f90-6c5c-41d5-a664-ae3be69717a2
Spec:
  Class:  io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
  Config:
    database.hostname:                                mysql
    database.include.list:                            inventory
    database.password:                                <nil>
    database.port:                                    3306
    database.server.id:                               184054
    database.user:                                    <nil>
    schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers:  debezium-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
    schema.history.internal.kafka.topic:              schema-changes.inventory
    tasks.max:                                        1
    topic.prefix:                                     mysql
  Tasks Max:                                          1
Events:                                               <none>
```

Kafka Connect:

```
Name:         debezium-connect-cluster
Namespace:    debezium-example
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: true
API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
Kind:         KafkaConnect
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-03-24T07:33:07Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:strimzi.io/use-connector-resources:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:bootstrapServers:
        f:build:
          .:
          f:output:
            .:
            f:image:
            f:type:
          f:plugins:
        f:config:
          .:
          f:config.providers:
          f:config.providers.secrets.class:
          f:config.storage.replication.factor:
          f:config.storage.topic:
          f:group.id:
          f:offset.storage.replication.factor:
          f:offset.storage.topic:
          f:status.storage.replication.factor:
          f:status.storage.topic:
          f:topic.creation.enable:
        f:replicas:
        f:version:
    Manager:      kubectl-create
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-03-24T07:33:07Z
    API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
        f:connectorPlugins:
        f:labelSelector:
        f:observedGeneration:
        f:replicas:
        f:url:
    Manager:         strimzi-cluster-operator
    Operation:       Update
    Subresource:     status
    Time:            2023-03-24T07:42:02Z
  Resource Version:  201434
  UID:               145f9996-73f9-4517-8b10-146081cf635a
Spec:
  Bootstrap Servers:  debezium-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
  Build:
    Output:
      Image:  [REDACTED]
      Type:   docker
    Plugins:
      Artifacts:
        Type:  tgz
        URL:   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql/2.1.3.Final/debezium-connector-mysql-2.1.3.Final-plugin.tar.gz
      Name:    debezium-mysql-connector
  Config:
    config.providers:                   secrets
    config.providers.secrets.class:     io.strimzi.kafka.KubernetesSecretConfigProvider
    config.storage.replication.factor:  -1
    config.storage.topic:               connect-cluster-configs
    group.id:                           connect-cluster
    offset.storage.replication.factor:  -1
    offset.storage.topic:               connect-cluster-offsets
    status.storage.replication.factor:  -1
    status.storage.topic:               connect-cluster-status
    topic.creation.enable:              true
  Replicas:                             1
  Version:                              3.4.0
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-03-24T07:42:01.787955422Z
    Message:               database.password: A null value is not allowed for this key
    Reason:                InvalidConfigParameterException
    Status:                True
    Type:                  NotReady
  Connector Plugins:
    Class:              io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            2.1.3.Final
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            3.4.0
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            3.4.0
    Class:              org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector
    Type:               source
    Version:            3.4.0
  Label Selector:       strimzi.io/cluster=debezium-connect-cluster,strimzi.io/name=debezium-connect-cluster-connect,strimzi.io/kind=KafkaConnect
  Observed Generation:  1
  Replicas:             1
  URL:                  http://debezium-connect-cluster-connect-api.debezium-example.svc:8083
...
```

Somehow the connector cannot read database username and password from `debezium-secret`, but I don't see what could be missing.

I've spent some time googling and found this, but the error message is different:

[Strimzi KafkaConnect & Connector Error, Won't Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71330652/strimzi-kafkaconnect-connector-error-wont-load)

Comment: You should doublecheck how you create the KafkaConnector resource. My guess is that the `${...}` were replaced already in your shell and what you passed to Kubernetes were empty fields. You should ideally just store the YAML in file and use `kubectl apply -f ...` to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem thanks to Jakub's comment.

The problem was due to `${...}` strings were not escaped and thus replaced by the shell before passing to Kubernetes. Storing the YAML part in a file followed by using `kubectl apply -f ...` did the trick.